# Merging Ontology by using rdflib

Tags: python, owl, ontology, semantic-web, rdflib

I have two files one ttl and owl. And I need to merge both of them together and create an equivalences as triples. I am using the pizza ontology.

One file is cw_onto.owl and other pizza.ttl

Comment: "merge" means what? I mean, just adding both to the same RDF graph is what rdflib allows you. What else do you need? Adding equivalent class axioms is just adding RDF triples, can also be done by rdflib

Comment: The RDFX library / command line util can be used to merge different RDF formats. It uses RDFLib. https://pypi.org/project/rdfx/